# Integration test with respawn

Tags: c#, testing, testcontainers

I try to test my controller where I fetch item by id from repository. I use testcontainer and Respawn library. There is my case (pseudocode):

1. I put data to db -> `Item(Quantity = 2)`, entity is inserted to db with Id = 1 (id is autoincrement),
2. I run client method where I want to change Quantity so my post content is `Item(Id = 1, Quantity = 10)`,
3. Test compares Item by Id -> Test success
4. Respawn resets database
5. Database is clear, without any entities
6. I run second test
7. I put data to db -> `Item(Quantity = 2)`, entity is inserted to db with Id = 2 (id is autoincrement and Id has increased)
8. I run client method where I want to change Quantity so my post content is `Item(Id = 1, Quantity = 20)`,
9. Test compares Item by Id -> Test failed because item with Id = 1 not found

Maybe my approach is bad to test, but I wonder how to do that in the proper way, or maybe how to reset database and start from Id = 1. I don't wanna care about Id because now its depends on order of running test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, I added `WithReseed = true` in

```
_respawner = await Respawner.CreateAsync(_connectionString, new RespawnerOptions
{
    DbAdapter = DbAdapter.SqlServer,
    SchemasToInclude = new[] { "dbo" },
    WithReseed = true
});
```